# Problem with unreadable symbols in txt bash script session log

Tags: bash

How to read this unreadable symbols from a bash session script, is there any tools help me to understand what originally was written
part of the Script :

]0;itsadmin@itsclient: ~ [01;32mitsadmin@itsclient[00m:[01;34m~[00m$ tee script.sh <[K> /dev/null <<"EOFEOF"

> #!/bin/bash

[K>
[K> signal_handler()/[K{}

> tee script.sh > /dev/null <<"EOFEOF"

#!/bin/bash

signal_handler(){}

[A[A[A[A[C[C[K

[K

[K

[K

[K[A[A[A[A[C[C        tee script.sh > /dev/null <<"EOFEOF"

#!/bin/bash

signal_handler(){}

[A[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}
[1P}
[A}

[K

[K[A[A[A[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C}

[K

[K[A[A[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}
[1P}
[A[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C}

[K

[K[A[A[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[C[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}[1P}                [C

> ^C

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: `hexdump` or `od` can be used to view the file content with characters, octal, hexa, ASCII, ...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).